# ZSH: How do I echo a program's output to a temp file if the output has newlines and other special chars?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I'm trying to write a ZSH script so I can run an arbitrary script (say, a JavaScript app) and open the script's output as a file in another application (my IDE). Here, my thinking is to invoke it `./myscript.sh $(node main.js)`. Content of `myscript.sh` right now:

```
#!/bin/zsh
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/atom.XXXX)
echo $1 > $TEMPFILE
ide --file=$TEMPFILE
```

I'm running into trouble on the `echo` line. The application's output is markup, so it has a variety of whitespace, backticks, (single|double) quotation marks, alphanumeric char, symbols, and newlines in it.

I understand the issues have to do with the backticks and quotation mark species in the app's output. Some dummy output:

```
# Weightlifting Workout A

Bodyweight: 165

| Lift | ||| 1RM (lb) |
|---| ---:|---:|---:| :-- |
|**Squats**|100x5<br>*0.61xBW*|90x6<br>*0.55xBW*|80x8<br>*0.48xBW*|112.5 |
|**Deadlift**|250x2<br>*1.52xBW*|||257.1 |
```

I imagine the fix is that I need to wrap something around the `$1`, but not sure what. The newlines in the JavaScript output is messing with `echo`.

I've tried combinations of `./myscript.sh $(node main.js)`, `./myscript.sh "node main.js"`, `./myscript.sh "$(node main.js)"`

with `echo $1 > file`, `echo $($1) > file`, etc.

playing around with passing the app's output as the zsh argument or passing the app's name as the zsh argument and then the zsh script executing the app's name.

Can't figure out how to get this working without running into an error like "command not found: node main.js" or "command not found: #" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
TMPPREFIX=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/atom.
(){ide --file=$1} =(print -r -- "$@")
```

And invoke it as:

```
that-script "$(cmd)"
```

The quotes are needed as otherwise the shell would split the output of `$cmd` on `$IFS` characters. That's only for NL, SPC, TAB and NUL (the default value of `$IFS`), quoting characters, backtics, etc are not a problem.

But that's more typing than doing directly:

```
ide --file =(cmd)
```

Or if it has to be `ide --file=file` instead of `ide --file file`:

```
(){ide --file=$1} =(cmd)
```

`=(cmd)` is a zsh-specific form of process substitution that uses a temporary file instead of a pipe (for `<(...)`). `(){code} args` is an anonymous function.

Note that to output the content of `$1` followed by a newline, the syntax is either:

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" # POSIX
print -r -- "$1" # ksh/zsh
echo -E - $1 # zsh only
```

Not `echo $1` which would not work properly if `$1` contained backslashes or was something like `-n`, `-`, `-Enenne`... See [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Your script, modified:

```
#!/bin/sh
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/atom.XXXX)
cat >"$TEMPFILE"
ide --file="$TEMPFILE"
```

You would use this as

```
node main.js | ./myscript.sh
```

This passes the output of the `node` command to the standard input of your script.  The script then simply redirects its standard input to the temporary file.

Alternatively,

```
#!/bin/sh
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/atom.XXXX)
printf '%s\n' "$1" >"$TEMPFILE"
ide --file="$TEMPFILE"
```

and use the script as

```
./myscript "$( node main.js )"
```

(note the double quoting and the use of `printf`)

I know I switched to `/bin/sh` in the above examples, but you don't seem to use any particularly advanced `zsh` feature, so I thought that would be okay.

Related:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)